# How to avoid this question: "Non-existent agenda file. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?"

Tags: org-mode

When I create an `.org` file (`C-x C-f`, `find-file`), the following appears in the mini-buffer: "Non-existent agenda file. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?". The question is not asked when creating a `.txt` file, for example. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix the problem?

I found a [very old org message thread](https://emacs-orgmode.gnu.narkive.com/EpuuKxSd/o-non-existent-agenda-file-file-txt-r-emove-from-list-or-a-bort#post10) that discussed a similar problem. I checked the value of `before-save-hook` and it contains values set by `org-roam` and `vulpea` packages. If I follow the old thread, one or both are invoking `org-check-agenda-file` and "...if the current buffer has not been written out yet, this pops the question". If all that is true and still relevant after 10+ years of updates, is there a way to resolve the problem?

UPDATE: The value of `before-save-hook` is:

```
before-save-hook is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
Its value is (org-roam-link-replace-all t)
Original value was nil
Local in buffer error_when_creating_org_file.org; global value is 
(vulpea-project-update-tag)
```

I re-started emacs after removing `vulpea`, the behavior persisted. I re-started emacs after removing `vulpea` and `org-roam`, the behavior persisted! I checked value of `before-save-hook`, and it is `nil`. But `find-file` still queries with non-existent agenda file and asks to remove/abort.  So it appears that the issue is not due to either package nor due to values of `before-save-hook`.

Comment: What are the values in `before-save-hook`?

Comment: ... and perhaps more importantly, *why* are they in `before-save-hook`?

Comment: BTW, I changed the title: it is *not* an error, not by Emacs or Org mode in any case.

Comment: @NickD... re:edits, thanks. I updated post with value of `before-save-hook`. The packages (org-roam and vulpea) designate those values. Not part of `myinit.el`. My guess: org-roam updates its database when a file is saved, and vulpea updates file-level tag when a file is saved.

Comment: Rereading the question, I missed a possibly important point: does the question appear when you *open* the file, or when you try to save it? If it happens when you *open* the file, then `before-save-hook` is the wrong hook to check: maybe check `find-file-hook`? And maybe `org-mode-hook` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Following @NickD suggestion (thanks!), the offending function has been found (based on initial testing). It made sense to examine `org-mode-hook` because the behavior was specific to creating `*.org` files. There were several functions in that hook. The most suspicious one (I'll call it `problematic-func`) contained a call to `org-map-entries`. In my original post, I referenced an old message thread, which traced the unwanted behavior to calling `org-map-entries`. I removed `problematic-func` from `org-mode-hook`, and the behavior no longer occurs. I plan to use `(when (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))) problematic-func)` to resolve the problem (this is how the original poster on the old thread resolved their problem while maintaining the functionality of `problematic-func`.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I use "org-map-entries" to fold all properties drawers, I met the same error when I use org-roam-dailies-goto-today to create a org file.

Now I use org-element-map to replace org-map-entries, it works without any problem

```
(defun wu/list-and-fold-property-drawers ()
  "List all property drawers in the current buffer and fold them."
  (interactive)
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'property-drawer
    (lambda (property-drawer)
      ;; (message "Property drawer found at position %s" (org-element-property :begin property-drawer))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (org-element-property :begin property-drawer))
        (org-hide-drawer-toggle t)))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'wu/list-and-fold-property-drawers)
```